# PostgreSQL, Calculating Number Of Drivers?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rdbms

I have implemented a database for a taxi company. I have used PostgreSQL to create this database. I have 4 entities customer, firm, driver and bookings. Currently I am having trouble trying to find a way to calculate how many drivers there are for a certain firm.

In the driver entity a foreign key is used which is the 'firmid'. The 'firmid' creates a link which tells the database that a certain driver belongs to a certain firm.

In the firm table I have a column which is named 'no of drivers'. Currently I have to count the number of drivers manually that belong to a specific firm from the driver entity and input the integer into the column in the firm entity. Is there any kind of formula or some function that I can implement that can automate this process.

e.g If I was to delete a driver from the driver entity, the number of drivers in the firm entity for a specific record should decrement and vice versa for adding a driver.

This problem has really been bothering me for a week now.

*UPDATE 20/12/2014*

I have tried adding a constraint to check the number of drivers:

```
ALTER TABLE firm ADD CONSTRAINT numberofdrivers_check CHECK (driversno ~ (SELECT COUNT (*) AS drivers FROM driver d GROUP by d.firmno ORDER BY 01));
```

But I get the following errors:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint ~ bigint
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use a trigger to update the count in your "firm" table when you change the drivers list.

Comment: use a view. This is what they are made for.

Comment: This is rather simple.  But you should use sqlfiddle.com to demonstrate your tables.

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean by a trigger? Should I add a constraint?

Comment: `CHECK` has a different meaning. Your use of it looks like it comes from some other language. `driversno` can not be defined in an expression like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend against storing an aggregate value like this in the database. Just calculate it when you need it.

```
SELECT d.Firm_ID, count(*) AS Driver_Count
    FROM Drivers d
    GROUP BY d.Firm_ID
```

Comment: That works but the company want to store the number of drivers. Isn't there any way to calculate the values automatically in table instead of using the select query?

Comment: @MohammedSohaib The short answer is NO, postgres deliberately doesn't store the _exact_ number of rows in the table. This is to facilitate operations in a multi-user multi-connection environment, where the table would have to be locked on every operation so that the magic total could be changed. Let me echo the suggestion above to use a `VIEW` in which Joe's count is used to calculate the driver total. Unless you are letting the company see the internals of your work, the `VIEW` should look enough like a table to the external world for everything else to work.